# В 1С-Битрикс весь js поместить в noindex

Tags: битрикс

В 1С-Битрикс есть такая опция в настройках "Переместить весь Javascript в конец страницы". Как закрыть весь этот перенесённый js в тег **noindex**? В каком файле ядра выполняется эта операция (сбор всего js и перенос его в конец)?

Comment: Простите, а вам зачем? Это очень странное желание, если честно. Ну а вообще, там раньше никаких событий не было (следовательно, придётся изменять ядро, чего не рекомендуется делать). Если у вас какая-то обоснованная причина, может связаться с ТП, чтоб всем такие удобство сделали?

Comment: Я понимаю что желание странное, но того хочет SEO (:
Пришлось править ядро.

Comment: Вам нужно поместить вашего SEO в noindex и взять нормального.

Comment: Ну а какие другие варианты? Заказчику так нужно. Ничего криминального в ядре не сделано, переменной добавлено '<noindex>'.$js.'</noindex>' и всё. Понятно что после обновления нужно будет это контролировать.

Comment: @alek.kov понятно, что кто-то этого хочет. Но мы же спрашиваем о причинах? С чего вдруг такие стандарты? Может, мы чего-то не знаем про поисковики? С чего вдруг поисковику нельзя показывать код JS, если он его понимает, то возьмёт от туда только клёвую информацию. А в противном случае и без того не прочитается. Разве не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент, файл который мне был нужен найден здесь:

```
\bitrix\www\bitrix\modules\main\lib\page\asset.php
```

Метод отвечающий за перемещение js: **moveJsToBody**

Answer (score 0):

Править ядро это плохо. Тем более есть нормальный выход:
Создайте обработчик события `OnEndBufferContent` модуля `main`. В котором, по сути, выполните ту же операцию что и в `moveJsToBody`, только с учетом ваших потребностей.

Comment: к сожалению, не получится таким способом, т.к. это событие вызывается до того как весь js будет собран и перемещён в конец страницы.